# Plumbing issue with Toilet ONLY

Tags: plumbing

The toilet in the Master Bath is NOT clogged but, there is a forceful air compression into the bowl from an exterior source. All other toilets, sinks and showers seem to be unaffected by this issue. What could be causing the air to explode back into the toilet bowl?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the plumbing system is not vented properly.

The venting system is intended to equalize the changing pressures in the plumbing system and prevent situations like this.

Unless you feel pretty handy with plumbing you will probably have to hire a professional if you want this repaired.

Good luck!